# get .css() from stylesheet not from first element

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get a css property from the stylesheet and not from the first element?

As you can see .css() returns the actual displayed rgb value. Is it somehow possible to get the "overwritten" one from the stylesheet?

```css
.c1 { background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); }
.c2 { background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var rgb = $(".c1").css("background-color");
        $('#output').html(rgb);
    });
</script>
<div class="c1 c2">elem</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: in the DOM you may be able to find `document.styleSheets` containing your stylesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain javascript you can get an array of stylesheets using

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
```

If you get back a length > 0, external css is loaded. You can loop `sheets` and find your rule

```
for (var i=0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var rules = sheets[i].cssRules; // .rules for IE?
    for (var j=0; j < rules.length) {
       if (rules[j].cssText ... do something with the css here
    }
}
```

Note: This seems not to work in google chrome if you load an html file from disk (file:///). Other browsers not tried.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking an existing element that might have other classes overriding it, just make a new element and pull the background-color from that:

```
var rgb = $('<div class="c1"></div>').css("background-color");
```

edit: apparently you have to add the element to the dom momentarily for it to actually receive a background color. This code works (tested):

```
var temp = $('<div class="c1"></div>');
temp.appendTo("body");
var rgb = temp.css("background-color");
temp.remove();
$('#output').html(rgb);
```

Comment: I tried it, but this selector is not working, at least for me.

Comment: Yep, sure doesn't, whoops. Turns out the element had to be briefly added to the DOM to actually get a background color. I just edited my answer with code I tested to work.